# impossible to run eclipse/milo client example

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I want to read and write datas in an opc ua server with an application using a javafx interface and I use IntelliJ as IDE.

So, I try to understand how to use the sdk eclipse/milo that seem to give all the methods I need in Java, and I tried to run the examples given in the github repository: https://github.com/eclipse/milo/tree/master

- I did a new javafx project with maven
- I added the lines:

```
            <groupId>org.eclipse.milo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdk-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.milo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdk-server</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

to the pom.xml

- I did mvn clean install
- I added the lines:

```
    requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
    requires org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client;
    requires org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core;
    requires org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.server;
    requires org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client;
    requires org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.core;
    requires org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.server;
    requires org.slf4j;
    requires com.google.common;
    requires org.bouncycastle.provider;
```

to the module-info.java

- I imported the example files of the github repository in the src folder as shown in te picture below.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuMIy.png)

And when I run ReadExample.java I receive the error:
java: package org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.server.dtd does not exist

And some imports appear in red:

```
`import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.server.dtd.DataTypeDictionaryManager;`
```

from the class ExampleNameSpace

```
'import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.GenericBsdParser;'
'import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.dtd.DataTypeDictionarySessionInitializer;'
```

from the class UnifiedAutomationReadCustomDataTypeExample

I'm not a java or maven expert. So, I definitely need help to understand how to correctly setup the eclipse/milo sdk and use it.

Thank for your generous help.